# IONIC Build failed transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic2

I'm trying to run my IONIC app in my android device running the command ionic cordova run android --device. But when its building, cordova returns this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 51.779 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --device (exit code1).
```

The Output of `cordova plugin ls`:

```
com.synconset.imagepicker 2.1.8 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.3 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.8 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"
```

Comment: `Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat` - this indicates multiple definitions of the Google barcode library, most likely caused by a conflict of Cordova plugins. Please post a list of plugins used in your project (`cordova plugin ls`)

Comment: @DaveAlden I edited my post with the output.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and nearly the same setup. Did you try to revert your `cordova-plugin-facebook4` to version 1.7.4?

For me this was not a fix, but it's a workaround for now, just to get the app built.

If reverting the plugin fixes it for you, also have look at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/535.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Platforms -> android -> build.gradle

Add `multiDexEnabled true` under defaultConfig like this

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

This worked for me..

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/help-with-build-failed-android-ionic/94396/8